# iOS Cordova app crashes on startup with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

We are keeping getting a strange error on when starting a cordova app

```
Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.1 is starting.

[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fef81d10e00

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fef81d10e00'

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105fdcd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105a50deb objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105fe5d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205

3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f2bcfa ___forwarding___ + 970

4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f2b8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

5   ◊©◊ï◊ú◊ô◊ß.◊†◊ò                     0x0000000105527ab3 -[CDVViewController viewDidLoad] + 195

6   ◊©◊ï◊ú◊ô◊ß.◊†◊ò                     0x0000000105525a06 -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] + 54

7   UIKit                               0x0000000106bf5984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198

8   UIKit                               0x0000000106bf5cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27

9   UIKit                               0x0000000106acbfb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61

10  UIKit                               0x0000000106acc69d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282

11  UIKit                               0x0000000106ade180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42

12  ◊©◊ï◊ú◊ô◊ß.◊†◊ò                     0x000000010552b188 -[CDVAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 776
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem with a Visual Studio TACO project. In particular this appeared when updated the Cordova CLI platform version from 5.1.1 to 6.1.1. This resulted in the modification of the native version of iOS Cordova from the 3.8.2 to 4.1.1 which produced the problem commented.

After many tests I found the solution. The problem was caused by file `'build.xconfig'` located in `'[project_folder]/res/native/ios/cordova'`. After delete this file and recompile the project the problem was solved.

[image]